# why my react code not working although other stuff is okay

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

decided to make react project for the first time, noticed that it's not working, css is good, but not react code, checked a lot tutorials but haven't found any solution:(

P.s this is my first time using react,therefore sorry guys and thanks for feedback

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="restaurant"></div>

    <script src="js.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js.js:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from "./App"

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("restaurant"))
ReactDOM.render(<h1>hiii</h1>, document.getElementById("restaurant"))
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react"
import Header from 'header'


export default function App() {
    return(
        <Header />
    )
}
```

Header.js :

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Header(){
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='head-part'>

                <h1>HopeLake</h1>
                <div className='icons'>
                    <span>i1</span>
                    <span>i2</span>
                    <span>i3</span>
                </div>
                <div className='list-pages'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>HOME</li>
                        <li>ABOUT</li>
                        <li>MENU</li>
                        <li>ORDER</li>
                        <li>CONTACT</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: [Upgrade to v18 note](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis).

Comment: What is your problem? If you start to write a new project, you can create it by using [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) or [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/). Because I saw that you try to create the fundamental of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example to use React.JS by CDN.
No need to export default but need to import file in index.html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Import new component before use here!!! -->
        <script type="text/babel" src="./App.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="./Header.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
    return <Header/>
}
```

Header.js

```
const Header = () => {
    return <div>This is my header</div>
}
```

index.js

```
const container = document.querySelector("#root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

Hope this will help you...